# Windows server 2012 doesn't show on network client

Tags: windows-server-2012

i'm setting up a windows server 2012 as file server and print share server. This is a small network (6 PC) so there's no domain.

The server name is "Omega" and ip is: "192.168.1.123"

I can ping the server, connect to it via RDP and see share just typing "\192.168.1.123" or "\Omega" however if i browse the network from Windows 8/7 or linux client i can't see the server (but i can see all other windows machines)

All computer are in the same Workgroup (the classic "WORKGROUP")

The problem seems similar to this one:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserver8gen/thread/aa387c3f-ad0c-429c-98c7-e66230592a15/

All required services to show on network are started, Network discovery in Network sharing center is "ON". I got the same issue with windows firewall on and off.

I need the server to be shown in the network because we got 2 "media center" that can reproduce media from network share but they cannot see the server.

Thank you in advance all help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue changing network location following this tutorial:
http://dandar3.blogspot.it/2012/04/how-to-change-windows-network-location.html

Enabling network discovery (these services must be started: DNS Client, Function Discovery Resource Publication, SSDP Discovery, UPnP Device Host)

Comment: this did it for me. Function Discovery Resource Publication

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is an old post but I hit on it because I forgot several important services that must be running.  The original post said `All required services to show on network are started` but I thought it would be useful for others to see that list of services that are required for the machine to show up on the network to other machines:

```
DNS Client
Function Discovery Resource Publication
SSDP Discovery
UPnP Device Host
```

Pretty basic, until you're the one who forgot it.  Cheers.